# Setting constants/enums at run-time?

Tags: c#

This seems like an odd request, I appreciate that, but this is the situation:

I have a program which depends on reading in a handful of files. These files are named like: `foo_bar_BAZ.txt` where BAZ is the name of the project and not known until run-time. However it will not change for the entire execution of the program.

I want to have an enumerated list of strings which stores all the filenames. So far I have used a sealed class like so:

```
public sealed class SQLFile
{
    private readonly String name;
    private readonly String value;

    public static readonly SQLFile CrByAuthors = new SQLFile("Changes_CR_By_Authors_%project_name%.txt", "CrByAuthors");
    public static readonly SQLFile DocumentCrMetrics = new SQLFile("Changes_Document_CR_Output_%project_name%.txt", "DocumentCrMetrics");
    [...]


    private SQLFile(String value, String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String ToString(string projectName)
    {
        return this.value.Replace("%project_name%", projectName);
    }
}
```

As you can see this depends on my providing the project name variable every time I want to access the filename, even though that filename is really constant from the very beginning of run-time till the end.

Is there a more elegant way to handle with this situation?

Comment: Getting project name through reflection?

Comment: Why not get `projectName` from a config file?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to have a static class with a `ProjectName` property. The value of this property is set during startup of the application. Your class then can use that property.

Comment: Globals are a maintenance nightmare and the purest from of evil from hell. :) But yes, nothing beats the simplicity of a global.

Comment: @Groo: That kind of unreflected / dogmatic use of generally good advice is what makes certain programs a nightmare in themselves. From the mechanics of a developer a constant is the same as a static property. Since he wants a constant, my suggestion certainly doesn't increase maintenance problems.

Comment: If he would have been in an architecture that makes use of DI, I would have suggested an interface `IProjectNameProvider` with a single method `GetCurrentProjectName`. But it doesn't look like he is using that kind of architecture.

Comment: My issue is that I don't agree with the premise that we are talking about a constant (even though the question title calls it so). The purpose of OP's `SQLFile` class is pretty simple: given a project name, return a specifically formatted filename which will correspond to that project. Adding a fixed dependency to a global property is temptingly simple, but it makes the class know a bit too much about the rest of the world.

Comment: @Groo: I tend to agree with your last sentence. But without knowing the *rest of the world* I feel it is a shot in the dark to suggest general architectural improvements. My first suggestion would have been to pass in the project name as the constructor parameter, but the ctor is private for some unknown reason, so this didn't seem like an option.

Answer (score 0):

Add a static property to `SQLFile`, something like

```
public sealed class SQLFile
{  
    //...
    private static string sProjectName;
    public static string ProjectName
    {
        get
        {
            return sProjectName;
        }
        set
        {
            //optionally, you could prevent updates with:
            //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sProjectName))
            sProjectName= value;
            //else throw Exception("ProjectName was already set!");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit - I read the code a bit too fast, so this is what I actually meant:]**

The purpose of the (poorly named IMHO) method `ToString` is to return the name of a file corresponding to a certain project name. There is nothing wrong with that, although it may be a responsibility which might belong to a separated class.

You could, for example, refactor the code to express its intention more clearly:

```
interface ISqlFileNameProvider 
{
     string SqlFilename { get; }
}
```

Then have a simple ("poor man's") implementation:

```
public class SimpleSqlFileNameProvider : ISqlFileNameProvider
{
    private readonly string _filename;
    public SimpleSqlFileNameProvider(string filename)
    {
        _filename = filename;
    }

    public string SqlFilename
    {
        get { return _filename; }
    }
}
```

And then derive specialized implementation from here:

```
public class TemplateSqlFileNameProvider : SimpleSqlFileNameProvider
{
    public TemplateSqlFileNameProvider(string template, string projectName)
        : base(template.Replace("%project_name%", projectName))
    { }
}

public class CrByAuthorsFileNameProvider : TemplateSqlFileNameProvider
{
    public CrByAuthorsFileNameProvider(string projectName)
        : base("Changes_CR_By_Authors_%project_name%.txt", projectName)
    { }
}

public class DocumentCrMetricsFileNameProvider : TemplateSqlFileNameProvider
{
    public DocumentCrMetricsFileNameProvider(string projectName)
        : base("Changes_Document_CR_Output_%project_name%.txt", projectName)
    { }
}
```

First, note that `projectName` remains the parameter for the `constructor` of these specialized classes. There are no globals here. Next, even though you've added a bit of plumbing code to your project, it's easier to decouple your classes for simpler testing: you can create a mocked implementation of `ISqlFileNameProvider` and return whatever you like to test the rest of the functionality without writing to real data files.

I would certainly advise against using a global property. The fact that you can specify the project name as a constructor parameter means that you can easily test that your class behaves the way you want it to. And even though you think that it will change during project lifetime, you can easily encounter a scenario where you temporarily need to switch the project name in runtime. I would advise against using globals.

Comment: He doesn't specify the project name as the constructor parameter. It is passed to `ToString`, so whoever calls that method needs to know the project name. If that's not the callers' business to know, I see a real problem with his current approach.

Comment: @Daniel: true, I thought OP was setting the property through ctor. My bad, I didn't express my thoughts clearly enough, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Groo if I understand correctly you're suggesting to replace my current sealed class with this new method, and essentially all those class declarations each represent the way of accessing the file names like an enumeration? I think I have a lot of reading to do to understand concepts like interfaces and providers or even what `base()` represents